# I'm having issues getting AngularJS to display my table correctly

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an object that looks like this:

```js
[{'name':'Mike', 'age':21},
 {'name':'Joe', 'age':24}]
```

My angular/html code looks like this:

```js
        <table class="Names">
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Age</th>
            </tr>
            <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat-start="value in msg.object">
                    <td rowspan="2">{{value.name}}</td>                    
                </tr>
                <tr ng-repeat-end ng-repeat="value in msg.object">
                    <td>{{value.age}}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

The names show up fine and vertically how i'd want them to be in the table (first column),

but for each value of name i get both of the ages displaying instead of just the age for that person.

Can anyone guide me in the right direction here? I feel like I'm close but just picked up angular today so I'm new to it and ng-repeat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need a simple row repeat with 2 cells in each row

```
<tr ng-repeat="value in msg.object">
  <td>{{value.name}}</td>
  <td>{{value.age}}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Not hard to get overwhelmed sometimes and look past the obvious

Answer (score 1):

Your table format is wrong. Place the headers inside  and do a **`ng-repeat`** to generate **`tr`**

**DEMO**

```js
var app =angular.module('testApp', []);
app.controller('testCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.users = [{'name':'Mike', 'age':21},
 {'name':'Joe', 'age':24}];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="testApp" ng-controller="testCtrl">
   <table border="2">
      <tr>
         <td>name</td>
         <td>age</td>
      </tr>
      <tr ng-repeat="user in users">          
          <td >{{user.name}}</td>
          <td >{{user.age}}</td>
       </tr>
 </table>
</body>
```